# How can I change position of zoom in/out control in Google map?

Tags: java, android, google-maps

I use google map API in my project and I want to change the position of the zoom controls with this code:

```
 SupportMapFragment mapFrag = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    // Find ZoomControl view
    final View zoomControls = mapFrag.getView().findViewById(0x1);
```

This code works for me only for build debug 
and when I want to build release (signed apk), this code has an error:

> Error:Error: Expected resource of type id [ResourceType]

This error point to `0x1`.

How can I do it?

Comment: I had a similar issue. I ended up disabling built-in controls and created my own control views which looked similar to built-in ones.

Comment: what is the error?

Comment: Error:Error: Expected resource of type id [ResourceType]

Comment: this error only when Generate Signed apk

Answer (score 1):

Since it is working on debug builds and the error only exists in build release (signing the APK), try to disable lint rule in your build.gradle.

> To rectify this issue first press on the error to see which file
>   throws this error. Once inside the file, inside the class function
>   type this:
>
> `@SuppressWarnings("ResourceType")`
>
> Then head over to your app’s build.gradle file and under defaultConfig
>   type this:
>
> ```
> android {
>   lintOptions {
>     disable "ResourceType"
>   }
> }
> ```

Source: [Android — Error: Expected resource of type styleable [ResourceType] error](https://medium.com/@sidhanth/android-error-expected-resource-of-type-styleable-resourcetype-error-b8df48b85c32#.9ycvffr0r)